# AWS ECS Internal Communications Timeout

Tags: asp.net, amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

I have a AWS ECS setup. Services and Fargate tasks run in a VPC and in the same subnet. One of the services is a ASP.NET web-application listening on port 80. When another service sends a request to that application, the request is cancelled from the client side in 15s. The exact same services (Docker images) don't suffer from this issue in my local environment, hence my assumption that this is something to do with AWS.

I didn't find any relevant information in AWS docs or tasks, services, and roles configurations. Where can this timeout come from and how can I increase or remove it?

Here is the log of the ASP.NET application. You can see that the connection receives "FIN" in exactly 15 seconds after connection start:

```
2023-12-13T08:46:08.746+01:00   dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Connections[39]
2023-12-13T08:46:08.746+01:00   Connection id "0HMVRLR65I2GS" accepted.
2023-12-13T08:46:08.747+01:00   dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Connections[1]
2023-12-13T08:46:08.747+01:00   Connection id "0HMVRLR65I2GS" started.
2023-12-13T08:46:08.747+01:00   info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[1]
2023-12-13T08:46:08.747+01:00   Request starting HTTP/1.1 POST http://extension-web-page.abtesting/text - application/json 38
2023-12-13T08:46:08.747+01:00   trce: Microsoft.AspNetCore.HostFiltering.HostFilteringMiddleware[2]
2023-12-13T08:46:08.747+01:00   All hosts are allowed.
2023-12-13T08:46:08.747+01:00   dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Matching.DfaMatcher[1001]
2023-12-13T08:46:08.747+01:00   1 candidate(s) found for the request path '/text'
2023-12-13T08:46:08.747+01:00   dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointRoutingMiddleware[1]
2023-12-13T08:46:08.747+01:00   Request matched endpoint 'HTTP: POST /text => Text'
2023-12-13T08:46:08.747+01:00   trce: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointRoutingMiddleware[8]
2023-12-13T08:46:08.747+01:00   The endpoint does not specify the IRequestSizeLimitMetadata.
2023-12-13T08:46:08.748+01:00   info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware[0]
2023-12-13T08:46:08.748+01:00   Executing endpoint 'HTTP: POST /text => Text'
2023-12-13T08:46:08.748+01:00   dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[25]
2023-12-13T08:46:08.748+01:00   Connection id "0HMVRLR65I2GS", Request id "0HMVRLR65I2GS:00000001": started reading request body.
2023-12-13T08:46:08.748+01:00   dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[26]
2023-12-13T08:46:08.748+01:00   Connection id "0HMVRLR65I2GS", Request id "0HMVRLR65I2GS:00000001": done reading request body.
2023-12-13T08:46:23.742+01:00   dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Sockets[6]

**2023-12-13T08:46:23.742+01:00 Connection id "0HMVRLR65I2GS" received FIN.**

2023-12-13T08:46:23.743+01:00   dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Sockets[7]
2023-12-13T08:46:23.743+01:00   Connection id "0HMVRLR65I2GS" sending FIN because: "The Socket transport's send loop completed gracefully."
2023-12-13T08:46:23.743+01:00   dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Connections[10]
2023-12-13T08:46:23.743+01:00   Connection id "0HMVRLR65I2GS" disconnecting.
2023-12-13T08:47:48.751+01:00   info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware[1]
2023-12-13T08:47:48.751+01:00   Executed endpoint 'HTTP: POST /text => Text'
2023-12-13T08:47:48.751+01:00   dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware[4]
2023-12-13T08:47:48.751+01:00   The request was aborted by the client.
2023-12-13T08:47:48.751+01:00   info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[2]
2023-12-13T08:47:48.751+01:00   Request finished HTTP/1.1 POST http://extension-web-page.abtesting/text - 499 - text/plain;+charset=utf-8 100004.1499ms
2023-12-13T08:47:48.751+01:00   dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Connections[2]
2023-12-13T08:47:48.751+01:00   Connection id "0HMVRLR65I2GS" stopped.
```

CloudFormation stack, containing consumer (web-ui-server) and provider (extension-web-page) services, and the security group:

```
Resources:

  # web-ui-server

  WebUiServerTaskDefinition:
    Type: AWS::ECS::TaskDefinition
    Properties:
      Family: web-ui-server
      NetworkMode: awsvpc
      RequiresCompatibilities:
        - FARGATE
      Cpu: "256"
      Memory: "512"
      ExecutionRoleArn: "arn:aws:iam::XXXXXXXXXXX:role/ecsTaskExecutionRole"
      ContainerDefinitions:
        - Name: web-ui-server
          Image: XXXXXXXXXXX.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/web-ui-server:latest
          Essential: true
          PortMappings:
            - ContainerPort: 80
          LogConfiguration:
            LogDriver: "awslogs"
            Options:
              awslogs-create-group: true
              awslogs-group: "/ecs/myproject-dev/web-ui-server/"
              awslogs-region: "us-east-1"
              awslogs-stream-prefix: "ecs"

  WebUiServerService:
    Type: AWS::ECS::Service
    DependsOn: DevMyprojectNLBListener
    Properties:
      ServiceName: web-ui-server
      Cluster: !Ref DevMyprojectECSCluster
      TaskDefinition: !Ref WebUiServerTaskDefinition
      LaunchType: FARGATE
      DesiredCount: 1
      ServiceConnectConfiguration:
        Enabled: true
        Namespace: myproject-dev
      NetworkConfiguration:
        AwsvpcConfiguration:
          Subnets:
            - !Ref DevMyprojectSubnet1
          SecurityGroups:
            - !GetAtt WebUiServerSecurityGroup.GroupId
          AssignPublicIp: ENABLED
      LoadBalancers:
        - ContainerName: web-ui-server
          ContainerPort: 80
          TargetGroupArn: !Ref DevMyprojectTargetGroup

  # extension-web-page

  ExtensionWebPageTaskDefinition:
    Type: AWS::ECS::TaskDefinition
    Properties:
      Family: extension-web-page
      NetworkMode: awsvpc
      RequiresCompatibilities:
        - FARGATE
      Cpu: 256
      Memory: 512
      ExecutionRoleArn: "arn:aws:iam::XXXXXXXXXXX:role/ecsTaskExecutionRole"
      ContainerDefinitions:
        - Name: extension-web-page
          Image: XXXXXXXXXXX.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/extension-web-page:latest
          Essential: true
          PortMappings:
            - Name: extension-web-page
              Protocol: tcp
              AppProtocol: http
              ContainerPort: 80
              HostPort: 80
          LogConfiguration:
            LogDriver: "awslogs"
            Options:
              awslogs-create-group: true
              awslogs-group: "/ecs/myproject-dev/extension-web-page/"
              awslogs-region: "us-east-1"
              awslogs-stream-prefix: "ecs"

  ExtensionWebPageService:
    Type: AWS::ECS::Service
    Properties:
      ServiceName: extension-web-page
      Cluster: !Ref DevMyprojectECSCluster
      TaskDefinition: !Ref ExtensionWebPageTaskDefinition
      LaunchType: FARGATE
      DesiredCount: 1
      ServiceConnectConfiguration:
        Enabled: true
        Namespace: myproject-dev
        Services:
        - PortName: extension-web-page
          DiscoveryName: extension-web-page-myproject
          ClientAliases:
          - DnsName: extension-web-page.myproject
            Port: 80
      NetworkConfiguration:
        AwsvpcConfiguration:
          Subnets:
            - !Ref DevMyprojectSubnet1
          SecurityGroups:
            - !GetAtt Subnet1InternalMicroserviceSecurityGroup.GroupId
          AssignPublicIp: ENABLED

  # Security groups

  Subnet1InternalMicroserviceSecurityGroup:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
    Properties:
      GroupName: myproject-dev-subnet1-internal
      GroupDescription: ECSSecurityGroup
      VpcId: !Ref DevMyprojectVPC
      SecurityGroupIngress:
        - IpProtocol: tcp
          FromPort: 80
          ToPort: 80
          CidrIp: !Ref DevMyprojectSubnet1Cidr
      SecurityGroupEgress:
        - IpProtocol: tcp
          FromPort: 443
          ToPort: 443
          CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0
          
  WebUiServerSecurityGroup:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
    Properties:
      GroupName: myproject-dev-web-ui-server
      GroupDescription: ECSSecurityGroup
      VpcId: !Ref DevMyprojectVPC
      SecurityGroupIngress:
        - IpProtocol: tcp
          FromPort: 80
          ToPort: 80
          CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0
      SecurityGroupEgress:
        - IpProtocol: tcp
          FromPort: 443
          ToPort: 443
          CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0
        - IpProtocol: tcp
          FromPort: 80
          ToPort: 80
          CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include the details of the security groups assigned to each task/service.

Comment: @MarkB, updated

Comment: So your `WebUiServerService` is trying to connect to `ExtensionWebPageService` on port `80`? You need to make sure `WebUiServerService` is trying to connect to the *private* IP of `ExtensionWebPageService`. I see `ExtensionWebPageService` has public IP enabled, but the security group rules will only allow incoming traffic via the private IP.

Comment: Services communicate internally via Service Connect using the resolve name. Public IP is an AWS ECS artifact, which is needed for some reason for the whole setup to function, but as you correctly noticed, it is blocked by security group.

Comment: OK, so did you use something like ECS Exec to debug this, and verify that the Service Connect addresses are resolving to the private IP?

Comment: As you can see in the logs, the request reaches the destination and the connection is established. There are also other microservices which respond in less than 15s, and all communications are working fine.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand that from the logs. I thought it was failing to connect. I found in the App Mesh documentation (which Service Connect uses) that there is a limit of 15 seconds on connections by default: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/app-mesh/latest/userguide/troubleshooting-connectivity.html You have to configure it with higher timeout settings.